# Springframework .NET 4.0 console application from a intranet share

Tags: .net-4.0, console-application, spring.net, trust

I've recently migrated a .NET 3.5 console application, which uses spring and nhiberate to .NET 4.0.  This application ran fine off of network shares under .net 3.5 and off of a local drive under .net 4.0, however once I migrated it to .net 4.0, I get the following error at startup from a network share:

```
    Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Spring.Context.Support.ContextRegistry' threw an exception. 
    ---> Common.Logging.ConfigurationException: Failed obtaining configuration for Common.Logging from configuration section 'common/logging'. 
    ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for common/logging: That assembly does not allow partially trusted callers. (Z:\Tools\SaaSDataPoster\SaaSDataPoster.exe.Config line 6) 
    ---> System.Security.SecurityException: That assembly does not allow partially trusted callers.
       at System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.ThrowSecurityException(RuntimeAssembly asm, PermissionSet granted, PermissionSet refused, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal rmh, SecurityAction action, Object demand, IPermission permThatFailed)
       at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
       at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache)
       at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache)
       at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
       at System.Configuration.TypeUtil.CreateInstanceWithReflectionPermission(Type type)
       at System.Configuration.RuntimeConfigurationRecord.RuntimeConfigurationFactory.Init(RuntimeConfigurationRecord configRecord, FactoryRecord factoryRecord)
       at System.Configuration.RuntimeConfigurationRecord.RuntimeConfigurationFactory.InitWithRestrictedPermissions(RuntimeConfigurationRecord configRecord, FactoryRecord factoryRecord)
       at System.Configuration.RuntimeConfigurationRecord.CreateSectionFactory(FactoryRecord factoryRecord)
       at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.FindAndEnsureFactoryRecord(String configKey, Boolean& isRootDeclaredHere)
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.FindAndEnsureFactoryRecord(String configKey, Boolean& isRootDeclaredHere)
       at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
       at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSection(String configKey)
       at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
       at Common.Logging.LogManager.<>c__DisplayClass3.<BuildLoggerFactoryAdapter>b__0()
       at Common.Logging.Configuration.ArgUtils.<>c__DisplayClass13.<Guard>b__12()
       at Common.Logging.Configuration.ArgUtils.Guard[T](Function`1 function, String messageFormat, Object[] args)
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       at Common.Logging.Configuration.ArgUtils.Guard[T](Function`1 function, String messageFormat, Object[] args)
       at Common.Logging.LogManager.BuildLoggerFactoryAdapter()
       at Common.Logging.LogManager.get_Adapter()
       at Common.Logging.LogManager.GetLogger(Type type)
       at Spring.Context.Support.ContextRegistry..cctor() in c:\_prj\spring-        net\trunk\src\Spring\Spring.Core\Context\Support\ContextRegistry.cs:line 60
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       at Spring.Context.Support.ContextRegistry.GetContext()
```

I've tried adding `<NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy enabled="true" />` and using `CasPol.exe` to give the intranet zone full trust (This worked when the app was .net 2.0).

I'm using the spring.net binaries that are compiled for .net 4.0 as well.

My assemblies all have a strong name as well.  I'm not sure if that helps or hurts.

The `IsFullTrusted` property of my executing assembly returns true as well.

Has anyone had any luck with spring, net 4.0, and network shares?

Below is the output from `caspol -m -lg`:

32-bit:

```
    Code Groups:

    1.  All code: Nothing
       1.1.  Zone - MyComputer: FullTrust
          1.1.1.  StrongName - 002400000480000094000000060200000024000052534131000400000100010007D1FA57C4AED9F0A32E84AA0FAEFD0DE9E8FD6AEC8F87FB03766C834C99921EB23BE79AD9D5DCC1DD9AD236132102900B723CF980957FC4E177108FC607774F29E8320E92EA05ECE4E821C0A5EFE8F1645C4C0C93C1AB99285D622CAA652C1DFAD63D745D6F2DE5F17E5EAF0FC4963D261C8A12436518206DC093344D5AD293: FullTrust
          1.1.2.  StrongName - 00000000000000000400000000000000: FullTrust
       1.2.  Zone - Intranet: FullTrust
          1.2.1.  All code: Same site Web
          1.2.2.  All code: Same directory FileIO - 'Read, PathDiscovery'
       1.3.  Zone - Internet: Internet
          1.3.1.  All code: Same site Web
       1.4.  Zone - Untrusted: Nothing
       1.5.  Zone - Trusted: Internet
          1.5.1.  All code: Same site Web
```

64-bit:

```
    Code Groups:

    1.  All code: Nothing
       1.1.  Zone - MyComputer: FullTrust
          1.1.1.  StrongName - 002400000480000094000000060200000024000052534131000400000100010007D1FA57C4AED9F0A32E84AA0FAEFD0DE9E8FD6AEC8F87FB03766C834C99921EB23BE79AD9D5DCC1DD9AD236132102900B723CF980957FC4E177108FC607774F29E8320E92EA05ECE4E821C0A5EFE8F1645C4C0C93C1AB99285D622CAA652C1DFAD63D745D6F2DE5F17E5EAF0FC4963D261C8A12436518206DC093344D5AD293: FullTrust
          1.1.2.  StrongName - 00000000000000000400000000000000: FullTrust
       1.2.  Zone - Intranet: FullTrust
          1.2.1.  All code: Same site Web
          1.2.2.  All code: Same directory FileIO - 'Read, PathDiscovery'
       1.3.  Zone - Internet: Internet
          1.3.1.  All code: Same site Web
       1.4.  Zone - Untrusted: Nothing
       1.5.  Zone - Trusted: Internet
          1.5.1.  All code: Same site Web
```

Answer (score 0):

I partially solved this problem by adding AllowPartiallyTrustedCallersAttribute to the assemblies containing the types used to deserialize the config sections.